# Calling AFHTTPSessionManager.downloadTasks in AFNetworking 2 freezes the main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, semaphore, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I have a singleton class that contains a AFHTTPSessionManager *fileTransferSessionManager. In it i sometimes want to cancel all downloads, before starting them anew this is done running through the downloadTasks and canceling them. The problem is, that when the downloadtasks attribute is called, the main thread freezes if there are running downloads.

```
// My method canceling download tasks:
NSArray *downloadTasks =  self.fileTransferSessionManager.downloadTasks;   
for (NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask in downloadTasks) {
     [downloadTask cancel];
}

// In AFURLSessionManager.m
- (NSArray *)downloadTasks {
    return [self tasksForKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
}
```

Calls this method that freezes the main thread, because getTasksWithCompletionHandler with dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore) is never called:

```
// In AFURLSessionManager.m
- (NSArray *)tasksForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {
    __block NSArray *tasks = nil;
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [self.session getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks) {
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(dataTasks))]) {
            tasks = dataTasks;
        } else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(uploadTasks))]) {
            tasks = uploadTasks;
        } else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(downloadTasks))]) {
            tasks = downloadTasks;
        } else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(tasks))]) {
            tasks = [@[dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks] valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
        }
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    NSLog(@"current thread: %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    return tasks;
}
```

I have tracked the problem down to self.session getTasksWithCompletionHandler: never entering its block, and therefore the  dispatch_semaphore_wait will wait literally forever to unlock the main thread.

What can be the cause of this, i doubt its a bug in apples framework, so thats why i ask here before submitting it. Have i done any obvious mistakes that may cause this problem?

Comment: I solved the deadlock by running this method on background queue. But actually you can achieve the same by using async method provided by NSURLSession. You should probably post it on Github issues board for AFNetworking.

Comment: I have the same problem, posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944465/afnetworking-deadlock-on-tasks-tasksforkeypath .. but i'm already on a separate (non-main) queue and that doesn't fix it for me. How did you fix this?